# What exactly is template constants in c++, and how we can use them?

Tags: c++, cuda

Here is my code:

```
template<int BlockWidth, int FilterWidth>
__global__ gaussian_blur(uchar4 inputImage, uchar4 outputImage, 
                         int numRows, int numCols, 
                         int BLOCKWIDTH, int FILTERWIDTH)
{...}

int main()
{
    ...


    const int blockWidth = 16;
    const int filerWidth = 9;
    gaussian_blur<<<gridDimension, blockDimension>>>(d_input, d_output, 
                                                     numRows, numCols, 
                                                     blockWidth, filterWidth);
    ...
}
```

The compiler just kept saying it cannot match the parameters. After searching for a while, I also tried:

```
gaussian_blur<<<gridDimension, blockDimension>>><int, int>(d_input, d_output, 
                                                           numRows, numCols, 
                                                           blockWidth, filterWidth);
```

but it still does not work.

By the way, can you also explain why template constants were used when trying to squeeze performance out of hardware?

Comment: You got way too many `<` and `>`s, unless this is some sort of weird CUDA thing.

Comment: @T.C. The OP seems to be conflating C++ templates and CUDA kernel syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not template arguments; the triple shift is part of NVIDIA's non-standard CUDA syntax. You should remove your template declaration, the use of the arguments you provide is handled by the CUDA compiler.

(Specifically, get rid of `template<int BlockWidth, int FilterWidth>`. The arguments you pass with `<<<` when calling a device (or global) function are handled by nvcc.)

Comment: You can use templates in C++ code when using CUDA, but the `<<<` syntax is really a glorified way of passing extra arguments (similar to the implicit `this` pointer in member functions) so that you can access things like the thread ID. I'm not sure if nvcc allows you to have a `__global__` function template (quick searching suggests that it does), but even if it did, your example doesn't have proper template arguments. The second example in particular suggests you may be misunderstanding how templates work; non-type template parameters can't be specialized with types...

Answer (score 1):

The template arguments should be specified before CUDA `<<<...>>>` syntax:

```
const int blockWidth = 16;
const int filerWidth = 9;
gaussian_blur<blockWidth, filerWidth><<<gridDimension, blockDimension>>>(
                                                 d_input, d_output, 
                                                 numRows, numCols, 
                                                 blockWidth, filterWidth);
```